# Slick Group By aggregating more than one column

Tags: scala, slick

How can I do the following SQL query in Slick + Scala, can you help me?

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID, MAX(CREATED_AT) AS CREATED_AT, NAME, EMAIL
FROM USERS
GROUP BY EMAIL
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your query is wrong because `NAME` column should be specified in `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: And what version of Slick do you use?

Answer (score 2):

As @Duelist says, his query is missing **name** in the groupBy ... starting from there the query in Slick would be like this:

```
Users.groupBy(u => (u.name, u.email))
    .map { case ((name, email), group) => (group.map(_.id).max, group.map(_.createAt).max, name, email) }
    .result
```

You can find a better explanation about transforming groupBy and others here: [GROUPBY](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.0.1/sql-to-slick.html#groupby)

**Disclaimer**: I assume you are using Slick in its later versions at 3